# Direction cosines for 2D and obtaining angle in degrees

Tags: trigonometry

I am working with 2D data and direction cosines.  If the two direction cosines are:

\begin{equation}
DC_x = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
DC_y = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
\end{equation}

and we know

\begin{equation}
DC_x^2 + DC_y^2 = 1 
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
cos^2(\theta) + sin^2(\theta) = 1,
\end{equation}

can I assume the second $DC_y$ is really $\sin(\theta)$?

The angle (in radians) can simply be found using

\begin{equation}
\theta = \cos^{-1}(DC_x)
\end{equation}

and if $\sin(\theta)< 0$, i.e., we are quadrants 3 and 4,

\begin{equation}
\theta =\pi + (\pi - cos^{-1}(DC_x))
\end{equation}

and then the angle in degrees is

\begin{equation}
\theta_{deg} = \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} * 360
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen this concept before, but I'll proceed as I understand it.

[image]

$$DC_x(\bar{a}) = cos(\alpha)$$
$$DC_y(\bar{a}) = cos(\beta)$$
$$\beta = \frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$$
$$DC_y(\bar{a}) = cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha) = sin(\alpha)$$

Comment: Thanks, looks like you drew information from a polar coordinates approach for a 3D system with $x,y,z$, where DC's are the cosines of the angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. But overall, we agree $DC_y=sin(\theta)$.